# How to find the number of points in a each small boxes of entire box

Tags: python

Let there be some 10,000 points lying everywhere in a square box. And I divide entire big box into small n boxes. How to find the number of points in each small boxes?

```
'kp = all the points'
kp_list = []
for b in range(len(box)):#box -- small boxes
    if kp in box[b]:
        kp_list.append({b:len(kp)})
```

Comment: use the coordinates to figure out if a point lies inside or not. Do that for all points.

Comment: Could you point out to link/code

Comment: Ideally, you would be the one writing it.